# Disable orange highlighting in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

Sometimes I have this orange highlighting and sometimes I don't.  I don't know what causes it.  how can I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The orange highlighting marks commands TeXstudio does not recognize.

If you want to turn this off (which I would not recommend), you can do that by going to `Configure TeXstudio` > `Editor` > `Inline Checking:` and unchecking the box for `Syntax`.